# I receive a InfoPath Warning Message: Any user currently filling out the form in a Web Browser will lose their edits

Tags: infopath, form

I receive a warning message (sort of) in InfoPath 2010 when publishing my form to my SharePoint. The warning message goes like this:

> Any user currently filling out the form in a Web Browser will lose their edits. You might want to notify your users that an upgrade to the form is imminent

May I ask how can I notify my users that an upgrade to the form is imminent?

Comment: Send out an email? :-/

Comment: I am not sure if SharePoint allows sending email to many people that is associated to a particular form library if I need to notify them of a upgrade to the form - is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could only really do this with administrator-approved forms as you can quiesce them (which means it stops new forms from being filled out and you would then just allow enough time from then to allow users to complete any forms).  Here is how to do this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262613(office.12).aspx

Comment: Is there other ways for forms that is not administrator-approved? (e.g. those forms that submit to a form library)

Comment: No, you can only quiesce admin approved forms.